# Partial derivatives problem

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

I have a problem with the following paragraph:

"""

... If we set $y = f(x)$, the equation $g(x, y) = 0$ is an identity for $x \in U$; (nb we are talking about implicit function, so $y = f(x)$ is the implicit function defined by $g(x,y)$; that is to say $g(x, f(x)) = 0 \ \ \forall x \in U$)

We can then derive with $g(x, y) = 0$ respect to $x$ and obtain $$g_x + g_yy' = 0$$Hence the formula $y' = \large \frac{g_x}{g_y}$.

"""

I do not understand why if we derive with respect to $x$ we get that. Why is $$\frac{\partial g(x, y)}{\partial x} = g_x + g_yy'$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a form of the chain rule:
Given a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and $n$ continuously differentiable functions $g_1, \ldots, g_n:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}$ if we define the application $F:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
F(x)= f(g_1(x),\ldots,g_n(x))
$$
Then $F$ is differentiable and its $i$-th partial derivative is given by
$$
D_iF(x)=\sum_{k=1}^nD_kf(g_1(x),\ldots, g_n(x))\cdot D_ig_k(x)
$$
Where $D_if(x)$ denotes the $i$-th partial derivative of $f$ at the point $x$.
In your case, we have $m=1$ and $n=1$ with $g_1(x)=x$, $g_2(x)=f(x)=y(x)$ and $g=F$. Hence, there's only one partial derivative for each $g_i$ and usinge the formula above you get the result

Comment: awesome :-) can you also provide a link to this theorem?